# When Installing PyQt5 gives error 'pyuic5' and Python cannot import PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, importerror, pyqt5, pyuic

I tried to install PyQt5 on Ubutun but during instillation it gives error;

```
install -m 644 -p /home/hrn/Applications/PyQt-gpl-5.4/__init__.py /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/
cp -f -R home/hrn/Applications/PyQt-gpl-5.4/pyuic/uic /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5/
install -m 755 -p /home/hrn/Applications/PyQt-gpl-5.4/pyuic5 /usr/bin/
strip /usr/bin/pyuic5
strip:/usr/bin/pyuic5: File format not recognized
Makefile:1988: recipe for target 'install_pyuic5' failed
make: [install_pyuic5] Error 1 (ignored)
```

PYTHONPATH is showing correct path for PyQt5 but if I try to import module it gives error

```
hrn@hrn-nix:~/Applications/PyQt-gpl-5.4$ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct  8 2014, 13:08:17)
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PyQt5 import QtCore
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
>>>
```

Whatever I try, I could not solve. What am i missing?

Comment: The output is `#!/bin/sh
exec /usr/bin/python3 -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic ${1+"$@"}
`

Comment: Looks like the problem starts before the first log you provided -- stripping pyuic5 (removing the debugging information) failed, which suggests that pyuic5 is not an actual executable.

I'm suspecting you don't have all the PyQt dependencies installed when you tried to install it -- could you provide the full logs from your attempt to build PyQt?

Comment: @michel-slm I followed installation instruction in PyQt documentation. Expect the error that I mentioned above, there was no error.

Comment: I have the same error with trying to compile PyQt5. Would appreciate if you have info on how to resolve this.